# Lag when setting AVCaptureConnection video orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession

The problem in question uses `AVFoundation` to setup a camera whose output is displayed in a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, and is also processed as a pixel buffer. In order for the pixel buffer to be processed by the `- processSampleBuffer:` method, it must be provided in the correct orientation, which is dependent on the device orientation.

As far as I know, this can be done either by rotating the pixel buffer as its given in the sample buffer delegate method by accessing the raw pixel values in `-captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:`, or by setting the `videoOrientation` property on the appropriate `AVCaptureConnection`, which ensures the pixel buffer is provided at the desired orientation. An outline of the setup is as follows:

```
- (void)setupCamera
{
    AVCaptureSession *session = [AVCaptureSession new];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera error:nil];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    [session addInput:deviceInput];

    dispatch_queue_t videoOutputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.MyApp.videoQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_set_target_queue(videoOutputQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOutput = [AVCaptureVideoDataOutput new];
    videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
    [videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:videoOutputQueue];
    [session addOutput:videoOutput];

    // more setup
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    connection.videoOrientation = [self getCurrentOrientation]; // setting this to a new value causes the preview layer to freeze momentarily
    [self processSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]; // some arbitrary image processing method
}
```

This works as intended as far as the orientation of the pixel buffer is concerned, however, whenever the device is rotated to a new orientation giving `connection.videoOrientation` a new value, the preview layer freezes for a fraction of a second. Blocking the delegate method's thread (e.g. by adding a sleep) doesn't freeze the preview layer, so that's not the problem. Any help towards a solution is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve this?  Having similar issues..  But I believe the camera might be restarting when changing the orientation.

Comment: The issue is indeed that the camera restarts. 

I found that to solve this issue, I needed to set the AVCaptureConnection's orientation at the very beginning of the entire view lifecycle, before the AVPreviewLayer is even shown to the user. I suggest showing a spinning 'loading' wheel for a moment while this happens.

It seems like the lag is worst when you set it after you are already showing the video output on the preview layer. If you do it very early on, there isn't much lag at all.